# Networking: Binding a socket on all interfaces when interfaces goes up/down

Tags: c++, sockets, networking, network-programming, bind

I'm creating an socket that needs to listen on all network interfaces on a specific port.

I create it using INADDR_ANY, so the socket listen correctly on all local IP addresses.

My question is: what happens if a new interface goes up? Does the socket automatically listen to the new interface, or do I have to rebind it?

Example: My socket is already listening, and I create a wifi ad-hoc connection. Do I need to detect that a new interface is available (the ad-hoc one), and rebind the socket?

(I'm using C++ on windows right now, but the code will have to be ported to MacOS)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

INADDR_ANY really means *any* interface, not 'all' interfaces. As such it doesn't matter whether the interface even existed when the socket was bound.